# Nightly Glassfish on Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, glassfish

I'm having trouble with changing GlassFish version to Nigthtly. My Intellij says that it doesn't recognize it as a valid GlassFish home. Could somebody tell me step by step how to get through this?

Answer (score 1):

Soulution:

1. go to glassfish4/glassfish/lib/install/applications/__admingui/WEB-INF/lib/
2. change jar name to console-4.1

Although this works I cannot get it to work with the newest version of nightly build.

My mistake was to assume that it was Intellij specific problem, so I installed Netbeans and tried changing GlassFish there and the same problem occured, but this time I knew there's like million more questions on the internet about Netbeans than Intellij and of course I found a solution.